# Can I create my applicaton on Vimeo and my members in my site able to use it to upload video to their own accounts?

Tags: php, vimeo

I tried developing Vimeo API – OAuth and Upload feature base on vimeo.php library. My account (which create app to get Vimeo’s Consumer Key and Secret keys) can upload successfully. But other account Vimeo of members in my site, they cannot upload.

I noticed that when authorize the application, other account Vimeo of members in my site, they get warning as below: 
"
This app will not allow you to:
Upload videos to your account
Delete your videos
"

So should I change any settings in my application or other account Vimeo?

Please help me fix the issue.

Thank you

Ly Tran

Comment: What upload permissions has your app been granted? Often Vimeo only authorizes the app owner to upload videos.

Comment: Hi Dashron. Thanks your reply. First my app has been granted "upload on my account only" permission, second my app has been granted "uploader's account" permission (but it has got approvals from Vimeo yet :( ). So how can I implement upload feature for ALL member in my site? Please help me. Thanks!

Comment: I would contact vimeo directly (https://vimeo.com/help/contact) and explain why you need additional upload permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Going to re-post the explanation from the comments here for future reference:

Vimeo has multiple different upload permissions, and an app can be granted one or more of them.

- **Owner** - Only the app owner can upload videos through this app
- **PRO** - Only PRO users can upload videos through this app
- **PLUS** - Only PLUS users can upload videos through this app
- **Basic** - Only Basic users can upload videos through this app.

If you find a user is unable to upload via your app, compare the user in question with your upload permissions (you can find the permissions on your app page).

If you feel you need additional permissions, you can contact Vimeo directly at https://vimeo.com/help/contact and request additional permissions.